# Use Local Time for StackTrace timestamp in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

In the stacktrace property of the ResponseStatus object in a servicestack response, there is a time stamp as follows:

```
"StackTrace": [GetEmployee: 8/12/2015 9:09:35 PM]
```

The timestamp, however, is in UTC time. Is it possible for me to configure servicestack to always return the server (or local) time instead of UTC for stacktrace errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack consistency uses `DateTime.UtcNow` for performance and uniformity throughout the code-base. You can't change the hard-coded usage of `DateTime.UtcNow` directly but you can override the [OnExceptionTypeFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#overriding-onexceptiontypefilter-in-your-apphost) in your AppHost to modify/decorate the returned `ResponseStatus` which will let you replace the existing DateTime to `DateTime.Now` with something like:

```
public override void OnExceptionTypeFilter(
    Exception ex, ResponseStatus responseStatus)
{
    base.OnExceptionTypeFilter(ex, responseStatus);

    var parts = (responseStatus.StackTrace ?? "").SplitOnFirst(']');
    if (parts.Length != 2) return;

    var requestName = parts[0].Substring(1).SplitOnFirst(':')[0];
    responseStatus.StackTrace = "[{0}: {1}]{2}".Fmt(
        requestName, DateTime.Now, parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mythz. That just what I needed. Worked like a charm.